# How can I travel to India without passport? Passport is being held at embassy in Madrid

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, spain

I am an Indian national residing in Spain. The situation is I don't have my passport because it's at the embassy for another trip I was planning and I don't know if I will get it returned on time as the process is taking longer than expected. All they can tell me at the embassy is to wait. I will be traveling to India in January. I already made travel arrangements and purchased my flights. If I don't receive my passport on time, is there an emergency travel document I can get for traveling to India and back?

Comment: Every emergency travel document I've ever read about is good only to return to the home country from somewhere else. Never seen or heard of an emergency travel document that'd allow outbound travel from the home country. But maybe I've lived in a bubble. Ask the Indian Consulate in Spain, as the Indian Consulate would be the entity issuing an emergency travel document.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The OP wants to return home to India, so the emergency travel document would be perfectly usable for this.  The bigger issue is that applying for one would invalidate the old passport.

Comment: The moment the emergency travel document is issued, the current passport will be invalid. You can only travel to India with that and you have to go through the process of replacing passport (with police verification), which will take around 2 weeks and you will stuck in India till new one is issued and necessary visas are obtained. You will be in much more trouble.

Comment: @lambshaanxy The question says the OP wants to travel to India _and back_.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica They could apply for a regular passport in India.  But this is all kind of beside the point, since an emergency travel document is clearly not the best solution for the OP.

Comment: Anecdotally, I know it is possible for the Indian government to produce a copy of a passport held at a foreign embassy to be used for travel to and from India (with the previous passport NOT being invalidated). However, in the case I know of, there was an urgent need to travel (and lots of negotiation with the Indian high commission in the UK), so just having flights already booked is almost certainly not sufficient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If push comes to shove, you can always **request that the embassy return your passport**.  Of course, this might cancel any application process that you have pending with them.

Emergency travel passports are issued when you have lost your passport, typically require a police report or equivalent, and they both cost money and would invalidate your previous passport. So this option is strictly worse than just asking for your passport back.

Some countries allow frequent travellers to get a second passport precisely for cases like this, but as far as I'm aware India is not one of these countries.

Comment: most embassies allow you to get your passport back temporarily for some urgent trip. The application isn't cancelled, you just need to return the passport back to them when you return